# How to get the key of an OrderedDict at a given index?

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, icollection

I'm seemingly unable to find a quick solution for an apparently simple problem: I have a C# `OrderedDict`, and, utilizing prior knowledge of the order, want to retrieve a *key* at a certain position.

`OrderedDict.Keys` returns an `ICollection` object, but I could not find a straightforward way to retrieve an element at a certain position.

I have solved it for now by building a list in a `foreach` loop using `.Keys` and indexing that, but that does not seem to be elegant to me.

Coming from Python, I am basically looking for an `list(someOrderedDict.keys())[index]` equivalent. Is there something like that in C#?

Comment: the index would be the `key`...  Dictionaries are meant to be used with keys.

Comment: OP wants to retrieve the **key** and not the **value** - maybe `(DictionaryEntry(myDict[index])).Key`?

Comment: As far as I understood, `myDict[index]` retrieves the `Value`, not a `DictionaryEntry`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132598.aspx

Comment: You should be able to do `orderedDictionary.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ElementAt(index);`

Comment: `.Cast` needed `System.Linq`. But even then `.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()` has no `ElementAt()` method. Am I missing another `using`...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's `OrderedDictionary` you mean there is no elegant way bar writing your own class. The most elegant way (perhaps not efficient) using `OrderedDictionary` is potentially:

```
var key = orderedDictionary.Keys.OfType<object>().Skip(index).First();
```